# Как передавать данные из одного фрагмента в другой, которые не связаны между собой (из 1 в 3 минуя 2)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-bundle

Есть три фрагмента. Назовем их условно fragment1, fragment2 и fragment3. Надо сделать так, чтобы bundle передавал данные из fragment1 в fragement3 (fragment2 представляет из себя простое меню, которое никак не изменяется). Как это сделать?
Сейчас в fragment1 есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую отправляется аргумент fragment3 и открывается fragment2.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment3 fragment = new Fragment3();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("Key","DataOne");
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
            ((AppCompatActivity) view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

Однако данные способ не помогает, так как в fragment3 появляется ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:101)
    at com.example.test.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:73)
```

которая указывает на строку 73 `mRef = database.getReference().child(text);`
отрезок кода fragment3, отвечающий за прием ключа и передачу данных в child().

```
if (getArguments() != null){
        text = getArguments().getString("Key");
    }

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = database.getReference().child(text);
```

Что делать? Есть ли другой способ это реализовать?
схематичный пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google рекомендует использовать ViewModel с LiveData.

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
   private MutableLiveData<String> selected = new MutableLiveData<>();

   public void select(String item) {
       selected.setValue(item);
   }

   public LiveData<String> getSelected() {
       selected.getValue();
       return selected;
   }
}
```

В этом пример я использую String, значит передавать будем набор букв.
В родительском фрагменте, который будет отправлять значение

```
private SharedViewModel model;
model = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

И дальше просто в обработчике нажатия указываем нужное слово, которое будем передавать

```
model.select("DataOne");
```

Затем идем в фрагмент, который будет получать данные

```
    final SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity())).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    model.getSelected().observe(this, item -> {
        model.getSelected().getValue()//это пишем в том методе, в который передаем данные
    });
```

[Если что, вот ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#java)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы создаете fragment3 локально, передаете аргумент, но не показываете, соответственно объект будет удален СМ. Способов выхода из сложившейся ситуации несколько. Или передавать данные во fragment2 откуда будет передача во fragment3, или складывать данные в какой либо глобальный объект к которому имеет доступ 1 и 3 фрагменты (например Application или Activity)

Comment: а как второй способ реализовать?

Comment: В Application или в Activity делаете поле с нужным вам объектом публичным, либо с гетером/сетером, и с фрагментов дергаете это поле. Единственное вам придется для такого доступа в Application или в Activity хранить статичную ссылку на самого себя.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял код то вы пытаетесь вызвать один фрагмент из другого. Не надо так. Можно создать интерфейс, что-то типа:

```
 public IActionListener {
 void onAction (String data);
 }
```

В первом фрагменте создать его экземпляр, а в родительском активити реализовать этот интерфейс. И потом через это активити передать аргументы в нужный вам фрагмент.

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html

Comment: не подходит, так как у меня несколько кнопок в 1 фрагменте и еще к этому 2 фрагмент может открыть 3 фрагмент различных видов (либо карта, либо список, но для их появления нужно получить значение DataOne). Так что писать такое большое количество интерфейсов не очень хорошо

Comment: Напиши один интерфейс с несколькими методами под каждое действие. Как уже упоминалось выше фрагменты ничего не должны знать друг о друге и все действия должны проходить через активити.

Answer (score 0):

Фрагменты не должны знать о существовании друг друга, все переключения должны быть на уровне Активити. Это значит что по клику вы должны сказать Активити что был такой-то клик (дернуть нужный метод в активити, если надо туда прокинуть нужные параметры) а Активити стартует нужный фрагмент и прокидывает в него данные. Еще правильно использовать static метод newInstance для создания фрагмента. Почитайте как правильно создавать, переключать фрагменты и передавать в них параметры. В нете полно информации.

Comment: А пример есть данного способа?

Comment: посмотрите это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZYYjY2NSKk и вот эти уроки для начинающих http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/